# How to get an entity out of a NSEntityDescription

Tags: cocoa, core-data, entity, nsentitydescription

I have a NSTreeController (treeController) and a CoreData database. I want the entity behind the selected object of my NSTreeController.

I use this to get the correct NSEntityDescription:

```
[[[[treeController selectedObjects] objectAtIndex:0] representedObject] entity]
```

Now I have my testEntity and I want to assign the entity object described by the NSEntityDescription I get with the code above.

```
MyEntityClass *testEntity;
testEntity = ???
```

I can't find a method. Is there another way to get the entityObject behind the selected object of the NSTreeController?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you're using an `NSTreeController` to manage an `NSOutlineView`, the `‑selectedObjects` method of `NSTreeController` should return an array of `NSManagedObject` instances.

You can query those instances for their entities using the `-entity` method of `NSManagedObject`.

However, the fact that you're called `-representedObject` (not an `NSManagedObject` method) means that your tree controller is handling some other sort of object. What is it? How is your tree controller configured? What do you get if you log the output of `[[treeController selectedObjects] objectAtIndex:0]`?

Comment: Thx. I could solve this a totally other way. What I get back with [[treeController selectedObjects] objectAtIndex:0] is a custom tree node. Thats probably why it didn't work that way.